# how to avoid creating the duplicate microservice when there is an need of same functionality in layer A/ layer B

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices

i have single microservice , which is deployed in layer A , we copied the code and deployed it in Layer B to utilize the same, how i can achieve this with single microservice without duplicating, what type of pattern i have to use?

Comment: You could have deployed another instance of the same microservice in layer B, couldn't you (providing that the functionality is _identical_)?

Comment: this might better fit at software engineering, but what do you mean by "layer"? microservices are not usually supposed to replace your standard monolith layers like database layer and your business logic layer but be more of vertical slices (although there can also be a layer hierarchy). In any case, sometimes you simply cannot avoid code duplication that is something that is inherent to microservices if you follow a pure thought of separate codebases. In principle you can however still extract common code into libraries, but this needs to be a conscious choice to bring in common dependencies.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Layer A and Layer B is independent. wo what we achieve here is reusable microservice library function

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you really want, you probably looking for some kind of load balancing.
For this you may want to check [this](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/spring-tips-spring-cloud-loadbalancer)
Enjoy!